scala-cli test are not run with scalacheck
I use scala-cli and scalatest-funsuite. Here is the snippet
//> using scala 3.3.3
//> using test.dep org.scalatest::scalatest-funsuite:3.2.19
//> using test.dep org.scalatestplus::scalacheck-1-18::3.2.19.0

import org.scalatest.funsuite.*
// import org.scalatestplus.scalacheck.*

class HelloScalatestSuite extends AnyFunSuite {

  test("hello() must return hello when no args "){ 
    assertResult(20)(1 + 1)
  }

}

Upon scala-cli test . , the test must fail but the Test itself is not recognized.  Commenting out //> using test.dep org.scalatestplus::scalacheck-1-18::3.2.19.0 runs the test as expected. The same set of dependencies (scalacheck + scalatest works fine with sbt.
What am I missing with scala-cli settings ?

I think the problem is related to there being 2 test libraries imported at once. Not sure if ScalaCheck counts as one, but it appearing to cause the issue suggests something like that... the auto-detection scans the classpath I think, so something in there must be causing confusion.
It started working when I explicitly specified ScalaTest's Framework implementation to scala-cli:
//> using testFramework org.scalatest.tools.Framework

The fix would probably work in principle for any combination of test frameworks that end up not being detected.
I found this info by noticing that the scala-cli docs mention something similar for Weaver (using testFramework), recognizing the sbt Framework interface from that one time I read about how to implement your own Scala test framework, and searching for it in ScalaTest's API docs.

My bad that I missed to update my own post with my finding. Thanks @Finn Hackett for the update. This works
